# Oracle não exporta todas as tabelas

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, exportação

Estou realizando um export pelo banco de dados em uma instancia `11.2.0.1.0` full, porém ao verificar o `log` percebo que as tabelas que não tem registro não são exportadas.

comando que estou usando para exportar o banco de dados
`exp system/senha owner=freitechnew file=freitechnew.dmp log=freitechnew.log compress=N`

Alguém já passou por esse problema?

Comment: Poderia adicionar a o comando **FULL=Y** ao seu comando. Porque na documentação da Oracle, eles dão um exemplo básico assim: `exp user@DB FULL=Y FILE=PATH_TO_DUMPFILE`

Comment: Ao exportar com o usuario ele retorna o erro `EXP-00008: Erro Oracle: 1406 encontrado` e não exporta, vou tentar resolver esse ora-1406 pra ver se consigo exportar assim, obrigado por enquanto.

Answer (score -1):

se voce especifica o owner ele só pega este owner, para fazer do banco todo usar conforme abaixo.

exp system/senha file=freitechnew.dmp log=freitechnew.log  full=y compress=N